# Xam.Plugins.Settings CrossSettings.Current break unit tests

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

when running a unit test which saves data with Xam.Plugins.Settings CrossSettings is null and not complete the unit test

private static ISettings AppSettings => CrossSettings.Current;

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check for a null then? `... => CrossSettings?.Current;`